# Avoid SQL Injection in PHP file to a Firebird Database

Tags: php, firebird, firebird2.1

I have the following code in a PHP which works, but I suspect it susceptible to SQL injection. Am I right? The query is to a Firebird 2.1 database, not MySQL.

```php
$timesheetBatchNo = '221706';
$query = "SELECT DATEWORKED, ORDERTYPE, REFERENCENUMBER, REFERENCEDESCRIPTION, TASKORSTEPNAME, HOURSWORKED, RECORDEDNOTES, ADDITIONALFIELD_1 as EU_REFERENCENUMBER, ADDITIONALFIELD_2 AS EU_TASKORSTEP, ADDITIONALFIELD_3 AS RDACTIVITY";
$query .= " FROM TIMESHEETLINES ";
$query .= " WHERE TIMESHEETBATCHNO=$timesheetBatchNo ";
```

I believe instead of including `$employeename` in the SQL string, I need to parse the variable into the query.

I understand I should be able to do this via:
`ibase_bind_param($query , 1, $employeename);` or
`ibase_execute($query, $employeename);`  or
`$stmt->bindValue(':empname', $employeename);` but none of these are working right now.

Comment: You say _"none of these are working right now"_ but what errors are you getting? You can use [`ibase_errmsg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-errmsg.php) to retrieve any error messages.

Comment: I was getting errors to say I was gettign a boolean, which I now know was a result of the original SQL being incorrect, but I only figured that out when using the "cheats" way of passing the SQL statement. Now when I use the following, I get absolutely nothing. No errors or anything.

```

Answer (score 2):

As luukd has already confirmed, your current code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Most of the ibase_* functions return false on failure, so you can check and return the [`ibase_errormsg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-errmsg.php). This is a crude example, and you should not blindly return error messages in production as they can give hints as to possible attack vectors:

```php
<?php

$dbh = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password);
if ($dbh === false) {
    trigger_error(ibase_errormsg());
}

$query = <<<SQL
    SELECT DATEWORKED, ORDERTYPE, REFERENCENUMBER, REFERENCEDESCRIPTION, TASKORSTEPNAME, HOURSWORKED, RECORDEDNOTES, ADDITIONALFIELD_1 as EU_REFERENCENUMBER, ADDITIONALFIELD_2 AS EU_TASKORSTEP, ADDITIONALFIELD_3 AS RDACTIVITY
    FROM TIMESHEETLINES
    WHERE TIMESHEETBATCHNO = ?
SQL;

$stmt = ibase_prepare($dbh, $query);
if ($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error(ibase_errormsg());
}

$timesheetBatchNo = 123;
$result = ibase_execute($stmt, $timesheetBatchNo);
if ($result === false) {
    trigger_error(ibase_errormsg());
} else {
    // handle result
    while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($result)) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

You may want to try the [Firebird PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php) driver but I do not know whether it will work with your old version.

Comment: Please, never echo error messages. Production or not

Comment: Fair point! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Getting an error message about a missing semi colon on the line trigger_error(ibase_errormsg()); since that line has a semi colon, then I guess it is elsehwere, but I suspect I am closer than what I was.

Comment: Actually, it says unexpected, not missing.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo - `(...)` instead of `{...}` for the code block after `if ($result === false)`.

Comment: No errors now, no result, but no errors. So just checking my query detail. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonKing in your code, you define $employeename variable but one used in the query is $timesheetBatchNo. It seems your only problem is inaccurate code. Anyway, your question is how to avoid SQL injection and this answer is 100% correct. Whareas your problem is "why my code doesn't work". And the only way this question could make sense is a code that actually WORKS and features TWO queries alongside, one without prepared statements and one with, which clearly demonstrates that one query returns a value and another doesn't

Comment: You are correct I do refer to two different variables, I shall edit the original question to remove any confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @SimonKing manually editing your question doesn't make it any helpful. You should copy and paste the code you actually run, as well as its output. Without any photoshop and "oh I left out insignificant details"

Comment: If the database I want to connect to has an API then I imagine I am better off using the APO which would remove any SQL injection. I am not downloading masses of data so process time shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: That is your design / business decision to make, but it would maintain cleaner separation between the applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct. The code you provided is susceptible to SQL injection because it directly includes the $timesheetBatchNo variable in the SQL string without proper sanitization or parameter binding.

You should use parameterized queries or prepared statements.

```
$employeename = 'ALLSOPPC';
$query = "SELECT DATEWORKED, ORDERTYPE, REFERENCENUMBER, REFERENCEDESCRIPTION, TASKORSTEPNAME, HOURSWORKED, RECORDEDNOTES, ADDITIONALFIELD_1 as EU_REFERENCENUMBER, ADDITIONALFIELD_2 AS EU_TASKORSTEP, ADDITIONALFIELD_3 AS RDACTIVITY";
$query .= " FROM TIMESHEETLINES ";
$query .= " WHERE TIMESHEETBATCHNO = ?";

// Assuming you have a MySQLi connection established
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $timesheetBatchNo); // Assuming TIMESHEETBATCHNO is an integer, adjust the type accordingly if it's a different data type
$timesheetBatchNo = $timesheetBatchNo; 
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmateion. I didn't point out in my original question, but the connection is to a Firebird Database. Does your $mysqli variable only pertain to a mysql database connection?

Comment: It is true only if the value of the variable is coming from user input.

Comment: @user13964273 True BUT even if the input is not directly from user interaction, it is still a good practice to use parameterized queries or prepared statements to separate the SQL code from the data values. This approach helps prevent potential vulnerabilities and improves code maintainability.